# How do I decode a URL that was encoded with MVC's Url.Encode(string url)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm surprised the UrlHelper provides an encoder but not a decoder! Does anyone have the code for decoding or know where to find it in the MVC framework?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[HttpServerUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urldecode.aspx)

Comment: please fix this, as mentioned below it should be httputility, not server.

Comment: @boomhauer actually since this is in the context of a web request since he mentions asp.net mvc using `HttpServerUtility` is just fine. If it was outside of that context, you would have to use HttpUtility or better yet use the antixss library.

Comment: this is not correct answer, at least this will not work from MVC view

Comment: avoid the answer which consists of just links, because they could be down.

Comment: This is not working when I'm trying to pass encrypted string as url parameter in mvc. Decoding failed.

Answer (score 49):

Actually it should be [HttpUtility.UrlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx), not [HttpServerUtility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urldecode.aspx).

Comment: Actually: [both](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx) [exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urldecode.aspx)

Comment: @AndrewBarber both exists, this is right. But the `HttpServerUtility` does NOT have `UrlDecode` method. this method exists in the `HttpUtitliy` class.

Answer (score 6):

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Parameter);
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP MVC Core use this:

```
WebUtility.UrlDecode(string encodedValue)
```

Answer (score -4):

An encoded url will automatically be decoded when passed into a controller action. For example:

```
public ActionResult Index(string url)
{
    //url will be decoded here
}
```

Comment: This is simply not correct, can you justify your answer please?

Comment: This happened when I pass encoded value to action method.

Comment: This answer is correct. I have no idea why people are downvoting it - it will work fine.